# Javascript not obeying style changes in Firefox

Tags: javascript, inline, visibility, onchange

To dumb it down, I have the following code highlighting my exact problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script>
function updateR1(){
    if (c1.checked){
        r1.style.visibility='hidden';
    }
    else{
        r1.style.visibility='visible';
    }
}
function updateR2(){
    if (c2.checked){
        r2.style.display='none';
    }
    else{
        r2.style.display='table-row';
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr id="r1">
            <td>visibility</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="r2">
            <td>display</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        <input id="c1" type=checkbox onchange="return updateR1();">Hide row 1</input>
        <input id="c2" type=checkbox onchange="return updateR2();">Hide row 2</input>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> **Working example >** http://s.supuhstar.operaunite.com/s/content/testHideShow.htm

In Opera, Chrome, IE, and Safari, the first checkbox makes the top row visible or invisible, and the second checkbox makes the second row compressed/invisible or extended/visible. However, in Firefox, neither of these work. Why not? I've tried many variations of this, including writing the raw script in the `onchange` attribute and using other event attributes, but it always works on everything BUT Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised that it's working on other browsers...but firefox is not executing your JS for the right reasons...it's wrong. Here is how you JS functions should be:

```
    function updateR1(){
    if (document.getElementById("c1").checked){
        document.getElementById("r1").style.visibility='hidden';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("r1").style.visibility='visible';
    }
}
function updateR2(){
    if (document.getElementById("c2").checked){
        document.getElementById("r2").style.display='none';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("r2").style.display='table-row';
    }
}
```

BTW, use Firebug for firefox....your life will be heaven ;)

Comment: I.... don't use firefox, but thanks for the tip? I only have it to make sure my pages render properly, and thusly avoid downloading addons for it (When you have the top 5 and two lower browsers, you kinda don't want to deck out each one)

Comment: My 2 cents...try the firebug+firefox combo for sometime...your web development life will change forever...mine did :)

Comment: also, about your opening comment: I'm surprised Firefox requires this complex code to get the elements; I was self-taught and everything, but this method always worked for me until now.

Comment: I am self-taught too...but had never used your way of accessing things in JS. Looks like learning for both of us!

Comment: I tried to get Firebug, but it's not compatible with my version of Firefox :/

Comment: is the Firefox dev tools a good replacement, now? Not meaning to derail the conversation, but I felt it prudent to ensure up-to-date information

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox you'd need to do something like:

```
document.getElementById("r1").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("r1").style.display="block";
```

If you can use jQuery for this it provides browser agnostic ways to manage visibility (and pretty much everything else) :

http://api.jquery.com/show/

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Changing it to `"block"` is bad, as I don't want its display behavior to be that of a block, but rather a table row

Comment: @Supuhstar that's fine, I was just trying to show the general syntax to manage visibility in a way firefox understands. You can also just assign an empty string when you want to unhide, that will set the display to the browser & element specific default value